# Constructor is undefined in Android

Tags: android

I have this code but they show errors in

> ```
> myelement=new Element(getResources(),(int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
> ```
>
> (Error: The constructor is undefined.
>
> and
>
> ```
> myelement.mX=(int)event.getX()-myelement.bitmap.getWidth()/2;
> ```
>
> Error: mX cannot be resolved or is not a field
>
> and
>
> ```
> myelement.doDraw(canvas);
> ```
>
> Error: The method doDraw(Canvas) is undefined for the type Element

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

Element myelement;

private MainThread thread;  



   public GamePanel(Context context) {          
          super(context);             
          getHolder().addCallback(this);
          thread =new MainThread(getHolder(),this); 
          setFocusable(true);             
   }

 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

          if(myelement==null)
          {

              myelement=new Element(getResources(),(int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
                 return true;
          }
          else
          {               
                 myelement.mX=(int)event.getX()-myelement.bitmap.getWidth()/2;
                 myelement.mY=(int)event.getY()-myelement.bitmap.getHeight()/2;
          }

          if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
          {
                 myelement.mX=(int)event.getX()-myelement.bitmap.getWidth()/2;
                 myelement.mY=(int)event.getY()-myelement.bitmap.getHeight()/2;

          }
          if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
          {
                 myelement.mX=(int)event.getX()-myelement.bitmap.getWidth()/2;
                 myelement.mY=(int)event.getY()-myelement.bitmap.getHeight()/2;

          }
          if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
          {
                 myelement.mX=(int)event.getX()-myelement.bitmap.getWidth()/2;
                 myelement.mY=(int)event.getY()-myelement.bitmap.getHeight()/2;


          }

          return true;
   }

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

          super.onDraw(canvas);          

          if(myelement!=null)
                 myelement.doDraw(canvas);
   }
```

And:

```
public class Element {

Bitmap bitmap; 
int mX; 
int mY; 

public Element(Resources res, int x,int y)
{
       bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.ic_launcher);

       mX=x-bitmap.getWidth()/2;
       mY=y-bitmap.getHeight()/2;
}
public Element(Resources res, int x, int y, int idHinh)
{
       bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,idHinh);
       mX=x-bitmap.getWidth()/2;
       mY=y-bitmap.getHeight()/2;
}
public void doDraw(Canvas canvas)   {

       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, mX,mY, null);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the error you are seeing, and the line at which it occurs in your code?

Comment: where is your error ?

Comment: Elaborate error you are getting and also if it is run time then post error logcat

Comment: I have just edited them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** First, double-check your import declarations. There are several `Element` classes present in the Android API, i.e. [`android.renderscript.Element`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Element.html), which you may be inadvertently accessing rather than your custom `Element` class.

---

Your `Element` constructor requires a `Resources` object for its first argument. However, you call `getResources()` inside a class that extends `SurfaceView`, whereas [`getResources()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) is a method associated with `Context`.

`SurfaceView` is a subclass of `View`, that has the [`getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) method. So, instead of:

```
myelement=new Element(getResources(),(int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
```

try

```
myelement=new Element(this.getContext().getResources(),(int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
```

Comment: I tried but they still shows error as I edited in question.

Comment: @DangHoang Do you have the correct import declaration for your Element class? You may instead have an import statement for one of the other `Element` classes that form part of the Android API. (i.e. `android.renderscript.Element`)

Comment: @DangHoang Thanks. I've updated my answer as well with the second part of the solution.